# Adding web service bindings into SharePoint web.config using SPWebConfigModification

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, binding, web-config

I have a SharePoint web part which uses a WCF service. To be able to consume the web service in my web part, I need to modify the SharePoint web.config to include bindings and end points.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Hi, umit. This looks like useful code, but we prefer to keep questions and answers separate. From the FAQ: "It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question." So could you rephrase this in a question form and post your code as an answer? That way others can potentially post other solutions and vote on their usefulness.

Comment: Please take action on Mike's suggestion - as it stand, this question is inappropriate for SO.

Comment: Updated the question and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to do this, I put my web service configuration into a text file as a template. The text file (BindingTemplate.txt) content is as the following:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_AuthenticationInterface" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://{0}/MyWebService/AuthenticationService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_AuthenticationInterface" contract="AuthenticationService.AuthenticationInterface" name="BasicHttpBinding_AuthenticationInterface" />
</client>
```

I used the C# following code to modify the web.config:

```
string content;
string WebServiceServer = "example.com"; // <=== your host-name here
using (TextReader tr = File.OpenText(bindingFilePath))
{
    content = String.Format(tr.ReadToEnd(), WebServiceServer);
}

SPWebConfigModification modification = new SPWebConfigModification("system.serviceModel", "configuration");
modification.Value = content;
modification.Sequence = 0;
modification.Type =SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode;
modification.Owner = OWNER_CONSTANT;

webApp.WebConfigModifications.Add(modification);
```

I spent some time figuring it out. Hope this will help someone.

Comment: Hi @Umit, I am going to use a web service in my EventReceiver project. Is it possible to add programatically add endpoint of the web service to web.config, when my feature is activated or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

This was very useful but it missed a bit. Whereas the code can be deployed, it can't be retracted because a name wasn't assigned.

Use:

```
modification.Name = "bindings";
```

Also, having said that this is bindings, you (probably) can't still can't apply the settings if there are already settings there for:

```
serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
```

... inside the `system.serviceModel`

I've used the technique to insert the bindings and then the client end point gets inserted separately as this can change according to installation and in my case is set via a sharepoint list entry.